# Child changes position, rotation upon import in Unity

Tags: unity, transform-orientation

I am trying to export a model from Blender (2.9) to Unity via FBX.
Location, scale and rotation are applied to all objects in the model, but still the eyes rotation and position change upon importing.

Does anybody have a hint what to look at?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the future: You can just throw in blend files into Unity, it can handle those. No need to export to fbx.

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

I got a hunch and it worked. Here's what I did:

Joined the eyes into the cat model and then separated them back into single objects.